# How do I read a formatted file in Python?

Tags: python, file, format, character

I need to read data from a file that is formatted like so:

```
Jamestown                         20 Rocky Mountain                    34
Illinois St                       28 Ball St                           51
Tulsa                              7 Bowling Green                     34
```

I need Python to read one line at a time and get both team names ("Jamestown" and "Rocky Mountain") and both scores ("20" and "34").

How would I go about doing this?  I tried making this code to see if I could read just the team name, but for whatever reason, it doesn't work.

```
oneSpace = False
for char in fileline:
    if char == ' ':
        if oneSpace:
            team1 = team1[:-1]
            return
        else:
            oneSpace = True
            team1 = team1 + char
    else:
        team1 = team1 + char
        oneSpace = False
```

Comment: you just need to split the lines, with `str.split`

Comment: @Kasra: Just using `line.split()` is going to do the wrong thing here—e.g., it'll make `Illinois` into a team name and `St` into its score. He needs to be _slightly_ more clever than that.

Comment: @abarnert yep , surely !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
ll=[]
for line in file.readlines():
     ll.append(re.findall(r"(.*?)\s{2,}(\d+)",line)
print ll
```

https://regex101.com/r/wV5tP1/12

Comment: This works well, and with reading one line, I get the following output:

[[('Jamestown', '20'), (' Rocky Mountain', '34')]]

How do I format this so I can do ll[0] for Jamestown, ll[1] for 20, ll[2] for Rocky Mountain, and so on?

Comment: @ScottSinischo: You've got a list of lists, `ll`. So, `ll[0][0]` is `'Jamestown'`. Or, if you don't _want_ a list of lists, get rid of the `ll.append(…)` and just do `ll = …` and use `ll[0]` _inside_ the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the rule you're *trying* to write is to split on any run of 2 or more spaces. There are easier ways to do that. For example:

```
bits = [bit for bit in line.split('  ') if bit]
bits = re.split(r'\s\s+', line)
```

---

However, I'm not sure that's the right rule for this file in the first place. When you've got things in fixed positions, you probably want to parse them based on those fixed positions:

```
team1 = line[:34].rstrip()
score1 = line[34:37].rstrip()
```

… etc.

Why? Because consider what happens when you get a line like this:

```
Team With a Really Long College Name28 Ball St                           51
```

The output might truncate the name to make sure there's at least one space. It might even truncate to make sure there are at least *two* spaces. But unless you know for a fact that they're going to do so, your logic is going to break. Whereas going by actual column positions is guaranteed to do the right thing.

---

One more thing: Are you *sure* the columns are just separated by spaces, not tabs? Because if the string *really* looks like this:

```
Tulsa\t 7\tBowling Green\t34
```

… then you should be just using `line.split('\t')`—or, better, `csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t', skipinitialspace=True)`.

Comment: plus for complete explain

Answer (score -1):

While your code was overly complicated, it *could* be made to work with only a few changes—and there are real-life programs that do have to be written this way because, [unlike this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27323151/908494), there's no simpler solution.

So, let's go over it.

---

Your first problem is that you never assign `team1` to any starting value before you try to modify it. That can't possibly work; you're just going to get an `UnboundLocalError` as soon as you try to access the value that doesn't exist.

But that's also easy to fix: If you want `team1` to start off as an empty string that you can tack extra characters onto, just add this to the start of the function:

```
team1 = ''
```

---

Your second problem is that, after all the work you do to compute `team1`, you just `return` nothing, so the result will always be `None`. That's also easy to fix: change the `return` statement to:

```
return team1
```

---

And if you fix both of those problems, everything works! You can see it working [in this online interpreter session](http://repl.it/5kP).